# parseFloat returning NaN for Celsius to Fahrenheit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parsefloat

I am trying to write some logic to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit and when passed a negative value, it returns `NaN`. Not sure why. Here is my Fahrenheit offset:

```js
const fahrenheitOffset = (value) => (value * 1.8) + 32;
```

and here is my function:

```js
function celsiusToFarenheit(celsiusValue) {
  return parseFloat((fahrenheitOffset(celsiusValue)).toFixed(2));
}
```

and another function to convert it to a string:

```js
function celsiusToFarenheitString(value) {
  return `${parseFloat(fahrenheitOffset(value)).toFixed(1)}°F`;
}
```

when I run these tests, I get `NaN` rather than '-0.55'

```js
    test('returns Farenheit float if Farenheit output is requested and valid reading passed', () => {
      expect(temperatureConverter(
        '-0.55',
        unitTypesEnums.FAHRENHEIT.string,
        converterReturnTypeEnums.FLOAT)
      ).toEqual(celsiusToFarenheit(parsed));
    });

    test('returns Fahrenheit string if Fahrenheit output is requested and valid reading passed in', () => {
      expect(temperatureConverter(
        '-0.55',
        unitTypesEnums.FAHRENHEIT.string,
        converterReturnTypeEnums.STRING)
      ).toEqual(celsiusToFarenheitString(parsed));
    });
```

Comment: `fahrenheitOffset` doesn't seem to return any value

Comment: @IsaacVidrine its implicit w/ the arrow

Comment: What input are you testing with? I don't see a value for the variable `parsed`.

Comment: I believe your problem is that when this is called `const fahrenheitOffset = (value) => (value * 1.8) + 32;` the `value` is a `string`. Check what is the type of `value` there and cast to number with preceding `+` or `Number()`.

Comment: @mattherman logging out the value in the fahrenheitOffset function logs out 72 if I log it right inside that function.

Comment: @shiderz that won't help here, the string can obviously not be parsed as a number.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problems are in the test not parseFloat.  This snippet logs -67 in each format.

```js
const fahrenheitOffset = (value) => (value * 1.8) + 32;

function celsiusToFarenheit(celsiusValue) {
  console.log(parseFloat((fahrenheitOffset(celsiusValue)).toFixed(2)));
}
function celsiusToFarenheitString(value) {
console.log(`${parseFloat(fahrenheitOffset(value)).toFixed(1)}°F`);
}

celsiusToFarenheit(-0.55)
celsiusToFarenheitString(-0.55)
```

Comment: The -0.55 value is the fahrenheitOffset or the celsius value.

Comment: Converts -55C to -67F.  https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+-55+celcius+to+farenheight&oq=convert+-55+celcius+to+farenheight&aqs=chrome..69i57.11714j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I changed inputs to -0.55 to match your test.  returns                     31.01
31.0°F